# genfstab not working

Tags: linux

I mounted my sda1

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Then I call command genfstab

```
genfstab /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

I get an error:

```
genfstab: command not found
```

I got this error while installing arch-linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this.

I was running in chroot.